# Get absolute path from Uri in Android 10

Tags: android, android-10.0, storage-access-framework, imebra

I am trying to integrate `Imebra` library to load `.dcm` files inside the app. The problem is that as per the documentation, I need to pass the absolute path of the file to `Imebra` as shown below:

```
val loadDataSet = CodecFactory.load("myFile.dcm")
```

For opening the DCM files, I am using the below code:

```
 val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).apply {
                addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
                type = "*/*"
                putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
            }

            startActivityForResult(intent, RC_OPEN_FILES)
```

I am able to get the list of URI's for all the selected files using the below code:

```
 if (data != null) {
                val clipData = data.clipData
                if (clipData != null) {
                    // Multiple files selected
                    val clipDataUriList = arrayListOf<Uri>()
                    for (i in 0 until clipData.itemCount) {
                        clipDataUriList.add(clipData.getItemAt(i).uri)
                    }
                    processDcmFiles(clipDataUriList)
                } else {
                    // Single file selected
                    data.data?.let { processDcmFiles(arrayListOf(it)) }
                }

            }
```

I tried using `uri.getPath()` and creating a `File` using the URI and then getting the absolute path but none of them seems to work.

I am not sure if this the right approach to get the absolute path of the files in Android 10. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That was a false approach. You will not try to get a path from an uri. What you can do however when you need a file path is to make a copy to the file system first and then use the path of the copied file.

Comment: @blackapps Can you please attach some links that shows how to do this?

Comment: It appears that you do not read this site at all as your problem has been reported here twice a day the last months, Please read.

Comment: But open an input stream for the obtained uri and an output stream for a file path of choice. Then read from the input and writethat  to the output. It's about the same as copying a classic file.

Comment: Okay, I will try this. Thanks :)

Comment: this answer worked for me for all my case:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63032934/12401637

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sample app uses the file selector to open and display a file:
https://github.com/binarno/Imebra-V5-Android-Simple-Dicom-Viewer

The app delegates the opening and loading of the file (if necessary) to Android, then passes the file to Imebra via the Imebra [Pipes](https://imebra.com/wp-content/uploads/documentation/5.0/html/stream_classes.html#_CPPv4N6imebra10PipeStreamE).

While slightly more complex, it allows Imebra to read files also from external sources (e.g. Google Drive).

Disclaimer: I'm the author of Imebra

Comment: I already have gone through the code of this sample. The problem is that I am using the old version of Imebra which doesn't support this. The reason for using the old version is because I am unable to apply transformations in the latest version.

Comment: As per the docs, the code for applying transformations includes initializing VOILUT() class without passing any parameters but the same code shows an error when used with the latest version and asks for the parameters to be passed in the constructor.

Comment: Also, the line voilutTransform.setCenterWidth(vois.get(0).center, vois.get(0).width); shows the error. I was unable to solve these errors and hence tried the different approach to get the absolute path from the uri.

Comment: VOIs vois = loadDataSet.getVOIs(); // Get a list of contrast settings from the dataset
  if(!vois.isEmpty()) {
    VOILUT transform = new VOILUT(vois.get(0)); }// Use the first contrast setting. This is in the documentation for Imebra 5 (which differs from Imebra 4)

Comment: Why dont you add a member function to load from stream? And/Or load from uri? Then a normal content uri obtained from Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT could be used right away. Addng such a possibility should not be much work as you will open a stream for a file path too already.

Comment: @blackapps The library is written completely in C++, the Java wrapper is automatically generated by Swig.

Comment: And a java input stream can not be used by C++?

Comment: @PaoloBrandoli Thank a  lot. The solution in the comment worked. I have been trying to solve this for 3 days :)